# How can I refresh a select list with another

Tags: ajax, list, cakephp, select

I am trying hard to refresh a list after selecting an option of a second.
I have this list

```
<select id="ArticleShopId">
<option>Some options</option>
<option>Some options 2</option>
<option>Some options 3</option>
</select>
```

I have a seond

```
<select id="ArticleCategoryId">
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
```

When I select an option of the first, ajax should load the table `Shop` and update the second select
I create an action called admin_refreshCategoriesAjax

```
function admin_refreshCategoriesAjax($id = null){
    $this->loadModel('Category');
    // Le list recupere la valeur des IDs et cherche un champs qui a la valeur "name"
    $categories = $this->Category->find('list',array('order'=>'name ASC','conditions'=>array('shop_id'=>$id)));
    //return "toto";
    return $categories;
    #return  json_encode($categories);

}
```

I wish t create a ajax code to do it. Then I try doing it

```
$('select#ArticleShopId').on('change',function(){
    //alert($(this).val());
    //alert("/articles/refreshCategoriesAjax/"+$(this).val());
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'refreshCategoriesAjax', 'admin' => true)); ?>",
      data: "id="+$(this).val(),
      success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
      }

    })

})
```

but msg does not return my an array with the $categories values.
How can I correctely call my action admin_refreshCategoriesAjax and update my second select with the value of $categories?

many thank for your help, I spend half day on it  :o(

Note:
If I enter this in my URL

> `http://localhost:8888/web/admin/articles/refreshCategoriesAjax/1`

it return me well the array I looking for. If I changer 1 with 2, it return my other value. Then this part seams to work nice

Comment: Is this ajax generated by php or this js code is in custom js file? Because your url is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that in your function admin_refreshCategoriesAjax you are returning the array rather than doing something that will actually output it to the webpage.  You could do `echo json_encode($categories);` to get some output you can use without explicitly creating a view for that action.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding an `id` in the parameter, you will find an id in `$this->request->data`. To make your ajax request secure, use the following code into your view file:

```
$('select#ArticleShopId').on('change',function(){
     //alert($(this).val());
     //alert("/articles/refreshCategoriesAjax/"+$(this).val());
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'refreshCategoriesAjax', 'admin' => true)); ?>",
          data: {id:$(this).val()},
          success: function(msg){
               console.log(msg);
          }
     });
});
```

And the following code into your controller:

```
function admin_refreshCategoriesAjax(){
   $categories = array();
   if($this->request->is('post'))
   {
     $id = $this->request->data['id'];
     $this->loadModel('Category');
     // Le list recupere la valeur des IDs et cherche un champs qui a la valeur "name"
     $categories = $this->Category->find('list',array('order'=>'name ASC','conditions'=>array('shop_id'=>$id)));
     //return "toto";
   }
     return $categories;
     #return  json_encode($categories);
}
```

Now to fill the data in dropdown, return `json_encode($categories)` from your controller. And use `var result = $.parseJSON(msg);` in your ajax success method.

Comment: Great, I am going to try this later!

Comment: @user1395480 Then you not you are accepting any of the answer ?